# Midlet - JSR179 Getting "Location Request timed out" issue

Tags: midlet, jsr179

When I'm sending message with location co-ordinates through my Nokia 5800. I'm getting "Location request timed out" message. I am working in one project to accomplish this task. How can I solve this issue?? Any solution for this problem??

Comment: Hey did you have any success with this?